# How does netstat know the number of bytes received and sent?

Tags: c, winapi, networking, netstat

I want to create a simple application that displays the number of bytes downloaded and uploaded. I noticed that `netstat` does just that (when using the `-e` switch):

[image]

How does `netstat` knows this information, does it call a Windows API function or something?

Comment: You are asking two question: `1` How to retrieve per-adapter network statistics. `2` How is *netstat* implemented. Which one are you really asking? The question title suggests `2`, the question body hints towards `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netstat uses<sup>1</sup> the [IP Helper API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365798.aspx), which is a part of the Core Windows networking API. Running `dumpbin /imports` on netstat produces: (snipped for brevity)

```
IPHLPAPI.DLL
         140007000 Import Address Table
         1400080A0 Import Name Table
                 0 time date stamp
                 0 Index of first forwarder reference

                      A3 InternalGetBoundTcp6EndpointTable
                      A4 InternalGetBoundTcpEndpointTable
                      C2 InternalGetUdpTableWithOwnerModule
                      B5 InternalGetTcp6Table2
                      B9 InternalGetTcpTable2
                      B6 InternalGetTcp6TableWithOwnerModule
                      BB InternalGetTcpTableWithOwnerModule
                      BE InternalGetUdp6TableWithOwnerModule
                      80 GetUdpStatisticsEx
                      64 GetIpStatisticsEx
                      4D GetIcmpStatisticsEx
                      7A GetTcpStatisticsEx
```

The last 4 IP Helper functions are the ones you're interested in. [`GetUdpStatisticsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366031.aspx), [`GetIpStatisticsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365963.aspx), [`GetIcmpStatisticsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365936.aspx) and [`GetTcpStatisticsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366023.aspx)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This is the *most likely* answer to the question, but for completeness netstat also imports `QueryPerformanceCounter` which it might be using to produce the output. Without the source code for netstat, there's no way to know with 100% certainty.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Number of sent and received octets per interface may be obtained via [GetIfTable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943(v=vs.85).aspx). See `dwInOctets` and `dwOutOctets` from [MIB_IFROW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366836(v=vs.85).aspx).